# question with four choices

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I have this sentence in a Literature class:

> For Hemingway, the world was defined by strife: full of chaos, moral decisions and ambiguous moral boundaries, and inevitable pain.

- to what does each "and" refer?
- the word "inevitable" in the passage is closest in meaning to?

> a.  a certain
>
> b.  possible
>
> c.  apparent
>
> d.  unexpected

Comment: 1) I don't understand what you mean by "each and to what prefer?"  2) The question about inevitable may be readily answered with a good dictionary, such as the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary); if that leaves you in any doubt, you may click on the *edit* link above to revise your question, citing what you find in the dictionary and addressing more specific issues. Keep in mind that "A certain" does not mean the same thing as "certain".

Comment: I mean what is the words that "and" connect?

Comment: Is this sentence by you or written somewhere about Hemingway? Could you show the reference of sentence?

Comment: it is a passage on the TOEFL book

Comment: certain is correct. Inevitable means something which you cannot avoid happen to you.

Comment: @PersianCat "Certain" would be correct (sort of), but that is not a choice here. "A certain" means "A specific" and would not be correct.

Comment: @StoneyB Maybe you are right. Anyway it was my idea.

Comment: After some research I think no one of them can be correct. Maybe "A Certain" is a typo mistake because only "Certain" can be the correct answer. No one of other answers is a synonym of inevitable.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct, and why? What are the dictionary definitions of those four choices and the definition of **inevitable**?

Comment: I cannot decide to delete my answer or not! :^S

Comment: @Matt I agree with everything you say, particularly that '"certain" is the answer the original questioner was expecting'. It's still a bad answer - not OP's fault, I suspect, but OP's teacher's.

Comment: @PersianCat I think you should undelete it. It's a good answer, prompted by a bad question/answer passed to us (I'm pretty confident) in good faith by an innocent bystander.

Comment: I think this question is Too Localised. From what I can make out, all it asks is whether *inevitable* actually means *certain*, Which could be answered by any dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question about *and*, however, is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @StoneyB: Most of the upvotes are going to the answer addressing *what does "inevitable" mean?*, and the other issue is Lit Crit anyway. I don't see how ELL can have a future if it allows/encourages these kind of questions.

Answer (score 5):

After some research I think no one of them can be completely correct. Maybe *a certain* is a typo because only *certain* can be the correct answer. No one of the other answers is a synonym of *inevitable*. *A certain* means *specific* as StoneyB said above in comments.

The definition of [Inevitable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inevitable) is the following one:

> adjective
>
> 1. unable to be avoided, evaded, or escaped; certain; necessary: an inevitable conclusion.
> 2. sure to occur, happen, or come; unalterable: The inevitable end of human life is death.
>      noun
> 3. that which is unavoidable.
>
> Origin:
>   1400–50; late Middle English < Latin inēvītābilis. See in-3, evitable

The definition of [Certain](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/certain?s=t) is the following one:

> inevitable; bound to come: They realized then that war was certain.

I think *a certain* can be the answer if we suppose the question is correct.

Comment: +1. Do you think you could include StoneyB's comment that "a certain" means "a specific". Consequently, you might like to point out that the answer should really be "certain" rather than "a certain".

Answer (score 1):

Persian Cat has answered your second question.

I take it that what prompts your first question is the presence of two ***and***s—why does the writer say “A, B and C, ***and*** D?” instead of simply “A, B, C, and D?”

This may not admit of a constructive answer, because what is in play here is a matter of literary (or would-be literary) style. I suspect that what the author intends us to understand is that something or other is full of A, B, and C — and, *on top of that*, D. If that is the case, I feel he would better served by using a dash instead of a comma before the second *and*, thus:

> For Hemingway, the world was defined by strife: full of chaos, moral decisions and ambiguous moral boundaries—and inevitable pain.

In any case, it’s a pretentious and unconsidered sentence. Semantically, the *full of* phrase is probably meant to describe *the world*. Syntactically, however, the colon after *strife* implies that the phrase describes either *strife* or *full of strife*. Certainly the reader is led to expect that what follows will somehow characterize exemplify *strife*, but, alas, it does not: neither the *strife* by which the world is defined nor the striving parties are ever identified.

This is the worst sort of impressionist criticism: a string high-flown abstractions which sound as if they must mean something which you the reader are clearly not smart enough to understand, when in fact it is the author who is not courteous or craftsmanlike enough to put his thoughts in an intelligible order before laying them before you.

Comment: You are right. Honestly I couldn't find why the author has chosen such structure! Because of it I asked to find the original reference may find out it but I couldn't find it in any on line reference.